# Web tfs and Python3 integration

Tags: python, tfs

What is the right way to insert data from python into web tfs? 
I have results from Jenkins Automation for specific suite and test cases.I have extracted the results into a python script as a Json.  I would like to change the outcome of the same testCases in Web tfs. Please advise

Comment: Hi Natalie, welcome to SO! Please read up on [writing questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking your next one. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if totally get your point. Seems you just want to update TFS test case result.
You could **[use Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)** to handle this.  It will update test results in a test run.

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=5.1
```

Since you are using Python, it's able to use Python Script to Access Team Foundation Server (TFS) Rest API.

First you need to use Python to connect your TFS server. TFS uses [NTLM authentication protocol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833874(v=vs.110).aspx) , you should use  HTTP NTLM authentication using the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests_ntlm/) library.

*Code Snippet:*

```
import requests

from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth



username = '<DOMAIN>\\<UserName>'

password = '<Password>'

tfsApi = 'https://{myserver}/tfs/collectionName/_apis/projects?api-version=2.0'



tfsResponse = requests.get(tfsApi,auth=HttpNtlmAuth(username,password))

if(tfsResponse.ok):

    tfsResponse = tfsResponse.json()

    print(tfsResponse)

else:

    tfsResponse.raise_for_status()
```

More details take a look at this [blog](http://techieroop.com/python-script-to-access-team-foundation-server-tfs-rest-api/).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have used the requests library and  HttpNtlmAuth in order to connect to tfs. However, didn't use the the json part, so I have received a response in HTML form. I will complete the code as you have recommended.  I have another json from jenkins automation tests that I would like to use it's results and update the outcome of the same tests in tfs. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible to update  test results of tests. You could use **Rest API** to handle this. But it's not able to directly use Jenkins automation tests results to update TFS test case. You need to extract the test results fist then update them to TFS server.

Comment: Thanks, I did just that. I don't know how to update them to TFS. I suppose it can be done with reguest.post but there are many application/json in the tfs response. I kind a stuck

Comment: @Natalie When you call patch above rest api, there is a request body, `"id": 100001,
    "state": "Completed",
    "comment": "Website links are failing because of incorrect container id",`  It contain test ID, this ID is generated when you  run  the same testCases in Web tfs. Then you could fetch the test results run by Jenkins such as Pass/Fali/Block, then use it the state part. For comment part, you could add some info whatever you want comment.